# Django,HTML - How to allow user editing existing object attribute with the original attribute info displayed?

Tags: html, django

Hi I am learning web development using Django and now trying the create a page to allow user to update the object info and *showing the original attribute content*

I understand how to make user enter info of attributes when creating a new object,ie.

```
        <label>Some field name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="field_name"/>
```

And if I want to display, I should use

```
<br>Some Fielname: {{ modelname.fieldname }}</br>
```

But when it comes to allowing user to update the info of the attributes,I've tried some thing like

```
<label>Some field name:</label>
{{ modelname.fieldname }}
<input type="text" name="field_name"/>
```

But the original field info cannot be displayed, can any one help to solve this problem, Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

basically to update the values of an object, we create an html form which takes the attributes and then submit it using post request. The view function in the backend handels the update work. In your case you will have to first make a simple table of information that you want to display

Then you can either make each row a separate form or make whole table editable in one go. when you press edit button you will basically replace the table with your form and then either submit or cancel will have to be taken care of.

let me know If I was not clear..

Comment: Thanks so much Rohit, i understand the logic on this,but cannot figure out how to do this,is it okie for you to provide some very basic code to show how this could be done. Simple code would be okie, I can figure it out myself Thanks Rohhit

Comment: please see this link - https://bitbucket.org/jamesdabbs/django-formedable . I am in office right now and we use java spring here. so I will have to write a fresh one for you.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a very good documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms

> ## Looping over the form’s fields
>
> If you’re using the same HTML for each of your form fields, you can reduce duplicate code by looping through each field in turn using a `{% for %}` loop:
>
> {% for field in form %}
>              
>                  {{ field.errors }}
>                  {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
>              
>          {% endfor %}
>
> Within this loop, `{{ field }}` is an instance of BoundField. BoundField also has the following attributes, which can be useful in your templates:
>
> {{ field.label }}
>
> The label of the field, e.g. Email address.
>
> {{ field.label_tag }}
>
> The field’s label wrapped in the appropriate HTML `<label>` tag, 
>      e.g. `<label for="id_email">Email address</label>`
>
> {{ field.value }}
>
> The value of the field. e.g someone@example.com
>
> {{ field.html_name }}
>
> The name of the field that will be used in the input
>      element’s name field. This takes the form prefix 
>      into account, if it has been set.
>
> {{ field.help_text }}
>
> Any help text that has been associated with the field.
>
> {{ field.errors }}
>
> Outputs a `<ul class="errorlist">` containing
>      any validation errors corresponding to this 
>      field. You can customize the presentation of the 
>      errors with a `{% for error in field.errors %}` loop.
>      In this case, each object in the loop is a simple
>      string containing the error message.
>
> {{ field.is_hidden }}
>
> This attribute is True if the form field is a hidden 
>      field and False otherwise. It’s not particularly 
>      useful as a template variable, but could be useful
>      in conditional tests such as:
>
> ```
>    {% if field.is_hidden %}
>        {# Do something special #}
>    {% endif %}
> ```
>
> {{ field.field }}
>
> The Field instance from the form class that this
>      BoundField wraps. You can use it to access Field
>      attributes , e.g. {{ char_field.field.max_length }}.